# Strange behaviour of nested MUI Popper elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Here is a `Node` component which renders a `button` element for anchoring an MUI `Popper` element:

```js
type Props = {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
};

const Node = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const [anchor, setAnchor] = React.useState(null);
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={(e) => setAnchor(e.currentTarget)}>Anchor</button>
      <Popper open={Boolean(anchor)} anchorEl={anchor}>
        <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={() => setAnchor(null)}>
          <div>{children}</div>
        </ClickAwayListener>
      </Popper>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is an `App` component which renders multiple nested `Node` elements:

```js
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <Node>
      <Node>
        <Node />
      </Node>
    </Node>
  );
};
```

The application behaves as expected: opening all the nested `Popper` elements then closing the root `Popper` element and reopening it *does not also reopen its immediate `Popper` child.*

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Full code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vcpsvr?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Now here is an alternative version of the `App` component which inlines the nested `Node` elements:

```js
export const App = () => {
  const [anchorA, setAnchorA] = React.useState(null);
  const [anchorB, setAnchorB] = React.useState(null);
  const [anchorC, setAnchorC] = React.useState(null);
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={(e) => setAnchorA(e.currentTarget)}>Anchor</button>
      <Popper open={Boolean(anchorA)} anchorEl={anchorA}>
        <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={() => setAnchorA(null)}>
          <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={(e) => setAnchorB(e.currentTarget)}>Anchor</button>
            <Popper open={Boolean(anchorB)} anchorEl={anchorB}>
              <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={() => setAnchorB(null)}>
                <div>
                  <button type="button" onClick={(e) => setAnchorC(e.currentTarget)}>Anchor</button>
                  <Popper open={Boolean(anchorC)} anchorEl={anchorC}>
                    <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={() => setAnchorC(null)}>
                      <div></div>
                    </ClickAwayListener>
                  </Popper>
                </div>
              </ClickAwayListener>
            </Popper>
          </div>
        </ClickAwayListener>
      </Popper>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In this case, the application does not behave as expected: opening all the nested `Popper` elements then closing the root `Popper` element and reopening it *also reopens its immediate `Popper` child and the child is misplaced.*

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Why?**

Full code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bfctmx?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the code in the given link by you https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bfctmx?file=src%2FApp.tsx

What actually was happening,as when we were clearing the child component,it's state wasn't getting clear as it's associated click away event wasn't getting fired. You can check now. I have replaced,

```
onClickAway={() => {
  setAnchorA(null);
}}
```

with this.

```
onClickAway={() => {
  setAnchorA(null);
  setAnchorB(null);
}}
```

and this

```
onClickAway={() => {
  setAnchorB(null);
 }}
```

with this:

```
onClickAway={() => {
 setAnchorB(null);
 setAnchorC(null);
}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much by the way.

Comment: Most Welcome @GéryOgam